# Is try/catch is resources consuming operation?

Tags: java

I heard that instead of throwing exceptions and catching them in try/catch block it is more reasonable to return null in methods instead because try/catch is resources consuming operation. Is this true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is true what you have heard: a thrown and caught exception is more expensive than returning `null`. But, consider also the expense of maintaining all the callers of your code. They will have to check for `null`, and should you ever want to add more kinds of errors you will have to modify your callers.

Use exceptions for exceptional conditions. If an error is a common or usual case, then it's not exceptional: return a status code.

Answer (score 6):

Try/catch only takes a significant amount of resources if there is an exception thrown, otherwise it's practically none. Use them when they make the program cleaner. Returning null can be OK too. It depends

Comment: +1 Though it could be expensive if try catch is used inside a loop.

Comment: @Favonius: better to put a loop inside try catch.

Answer (score 3):

try/catch consumes trivial resources, however throwing an exception is relatively expensive.  Exceptions should only be thrown in exceptional circumstances, and shouldn't be a performance issue if used carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Even if it is true (to some degree), it is yet another (bad) case of premature optimization to use that as a reason to avoid exceptions in general.

Exceptions are for communicating conditions that will probably handled farther up the call stack rather than by the immediate caller. If you have such a condition, you should use an Exception.

Comment: +1 Very true `Even if it is true (to some degree), it is yet another (bad) case of premature optimization to use that as a reason to avoid exceptions in general.`

Answer (score 2):

You should throw Exceptions when the condition at hand is an *exceptional condition* that an Exception object can be useful for passing information back up the call stack.

You should return `null` from methods instead of an expected value when that is an appropriate, non-exceptional value that would signify "nothing here", or some equivalent.

For non-exceptional 'errors' where a `null` is not appropriate, you can often do something different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, throwing and catching exceptions could be an *expensive* operation. Exceptions should be thrown only in exceptional cases (cases which happen rarely). For example avoid throwing exceptions when validating some user input when you could return true/false.

Answer (score 0):

For me, try catch is just a way for catching ERRORS, if it's just because the function couldn't run, i would use a return value.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always true and depends on the situation. Imagine you can get three or more types of erros inside one method. Then, returning single 'null' value won't tell client code about the error type.

Also, simply returning from function is not always what you want to do in terms of flow control.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, exceptions are expensive when caught, but just putting try catch in your code is cheap (except when put in a loop, for example).

Although, ignoring them is a sign of premature optimization, since just returning `null` or `false` can hinder your control flow, since your code will become messy.

I've seen tons of `if ( something != null && something.exists() && something.isTrue() )` code in my life, and it's not pretty.